# What is causing stackoverflow in the following code

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I can't figure out why I keep getting stackoverflow error in the following code. What's causing it?

```
let rec fl x y ct = match x with
    [] -> []
  | (h::t) -> if haskey ct y = true then (fl x y (ct + 1))
    else h :: (fl x y (ct + 1))
;;
```

Comment: Note that `if haskey ct y then` is better.  In addition, you can also drop a few parentheses.  The second line becomes: `| h::t -> if haskey ct y then fl x y (ct + 1) else h :: fl x y (ct + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fl function infinitely recurses into itself:

```
let rec fl x y ct = match x with
    [] -> []
  | (h::t) -> if haskey ct y = true then (fl x y (ct + 1))
    else h :: (fl x y (ct + 1))
;;
```

The only change in the recursive call is the increment to ct. Presumably, you need some kind of terminating condition for ct, or you need to call fl with the tail of your list.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I struggled with such a simple mistake.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it (by clicking the button).